# how to create a copy of repo on github consistensly keeping a change?

Tags: git, github

there is a repo of data on github i'd like to modify a bit to make a publishable maven artifact.

1. make copy, move the test to resources, add a pom, change name to say where its from, publish it with std version number on maven

but I also want to notice when original repo changes and

2. simple update from original without pushing my changes

it basically is strictly separated project: my files to just make it a maven-java project; the original files moved but not changed by content

is there a simple algorithm for that?

Comment: How about simply forking the original project, and creating a branch in your fork with your changes? Then if the original repository is updated, you can pull into the master branch from the original repository and merge into your branch to update your copy with the upstream changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could add that project as a submodule of yours; take a look at the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: this might be the best version but a submodule should not be moved with os mv. that is a clear violence of git thinking.
trying fork as suggested by karslen now.
lets see who wins

Comment: Agreed, you certainly shouldn't, but I didn't follow why that would be necessary... Just add submodule and git pull whenever there are changes. Put your own files outside that folder. But now I think I don't get exactly what the question requires. Probably your solution is better :)